# libGDX project : "A fatal Error has been detected ... "

Tags: java, libgdx, eclipse-photon

I would be really glad if you could help with this unsolvable Problem (atleast for me ).

I get the following message when trying to run a LibGDX Project:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, 
pid=9992, tid=0x000000000000279c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Benwe93\Desktop\Projekt\core\assets\hs_err_pid9992.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

The Code is EXACTLY the same as on another Notebook Im using where I can run it perfectly. So it should not be codes fault ?

Anyway this is the message Im getting from the error Report:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=9992, tid=0x000000000000279c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000018b72000):  JavaThread "LWJGL Application" [_thread_in_native, id=10140, stack(0x000000001a7c0000,0x000000001a8c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x000000001e884090, RBX=0x0000000000187f00, RCX=0x00000000001efd30, RDX=0x000000000016a290
RSP=0x000000001a8bedf8, RBP=0x000000000016a290, RSI=0x000000001a8beec0, RDI=0x000000000016a290
R8 =0x0000000000183fb0, R9 =0x000000001a8beec0, R10=0x0000000002958c3b, R11=0x00000000605fc6a0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000017075b68, R14=0x000000001a8bf038, R15=0x0000000018b72000
RIP=0x0000000000000000, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001a8bedf8)
0x000000001a8bedf8:   000000006e9df82c 0000000000000000
0x000000001a8bee08:   000000002a00002a 0000000000183fb0
0x000000001a8bee18:   0000000000200021 000000000016a290
0x000000001a8bee28:   0000000000183fb0 0000000000187f00
0x000000001a8bee38:   000000000016a290 000000001a8beec0
0x000000001a8bee48:   000000006e9de6c9 0000000000000000
0x000000001a8bee58:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001a8bee68:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001a8bee78:   0000000017075b68 0000000000200021
0x000000001a8bee88:   000000000294835d 000000001a8befc0
0x000000001a8bee98:   000000006e9e49bd 0000000018b721f8
0x000000001a8beea8:   0000000000000005 000000001a8bf020
0x000000001a8beeb8:   0000000798111a00 00000000001efd30
0x000000001a8beec8:   0000000000000000 33d6bf953e4ccccd
0x000000001a8beed8:   0001000042480000 000000000000ffff
0x000000001a8beee8:   0000000000193f20 0000000000193f20 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000000000000)
0xffffffffffffffe0:   


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000001e884090 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000187f00 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000000001efd30 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000016a290 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001a8bedf8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018b72000
RBP=0x000000000016a290 is an unknown value
RSI=0x000000001a8beec0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018b72000
RDI=0x000000000016a290 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000183fb0 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000001a8beec0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018b72000
R10=0x0000000002958c3b is at code_begin+891 in an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x00000000029588c0, 0x0000000002959280]  2496 bytes
R11=0x00000000605fc6a0 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x0000000017075b70} 'jniCreateFixture' '(JJFFFZSSS)J' in 'com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body'
R14=0x000000001a8bf038 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000018b72000
R15=0x0000000018b72000 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000001a7c0000,0x000000001a8c0000],  sp=0x000000001a8bedf8,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body.jniCreateFixture(JJFFFZSSS)J+0
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body.createFixture(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/FixtureDef;)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Fixture;+49
j  com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.create()V+1479
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop()V+29
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run()V+27
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000001bef000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=10016, stack(0x0000000002570000,0x0000000002670000)]
=>0x0000000018b72000 JavaThread "LWJGL Application" [_thread_in_native, id=10140, stack(0x000000001a7c0000,0x000000001a8c0000)]
  0x0000000018885000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10068, stack(0x0000000018f20000,0x0000000019020000)]
  0x000000001735b800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10064, stack(0x0000000019360000,0x0000000019460000)]
  0x000000001735a800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10060, stack(0x0000000019170000,0x0000000019270000)]
  0x00000000187e6000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10056, stack(0x0000000019020000,0x0000000019120000)]
  0x00000000187e3000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10052, stack(0x0000000018c50000,0x0000000018d50000)]
  0x00000000187e2800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10048, stack(0x0000000018da0000,0x0000000018ea0000)]
  0x000000001733e800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10044, stack(0x00000000186e0000,0x00000000187e0000)]
  0x00000000172f7800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10040, stack(0x0000000018500000,0x0000000018600000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000172ec000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000018360000,0x0000000018460000] [id=10036]
  0x0000000018886000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000019560000,0x0000000019660000] [id=10072]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 36864K, used 14881K [0x0000000797300000, 0x0000000799c00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 31744K, 46% used [0x0000000797300000,0x0000000798188608,0x0000000799200000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x0000000799700000,0x0000000799700000,0x0000000799c00000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x0000000799200000,0x0000000799200000,0x0000000799700000)
 ParOldGen       total 84992K, used 0K [0x0000000745800000, 0x000000074ab00000, 0x0000000797300000)
  object space 84992K, 0% used [0x0000000745800000,0x0000000745800000,0x000000074ab00000)
 Metaspace       used 8019K, capacity 8169K, committed 8320K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 797K, capacity 859K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011d00000,0x00000000120e0000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000e2d4000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000060bf2d00
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012840000, 0x00000000146e0000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000000146e0000, 0x0000000016580000)

Polling page: 0x0000000001b90000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=2878Kb max_used=2882Kb free=242881Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002940000, 0x0000000002c20000, 0x0000000011940000]
 total_blobs=1102 nmethods=620 adapters=395
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1.497 Thread 0x00000000187e6000 nmethod 589% 0x0000000002c0cd90 code [0x0000000002c0cf20, 0x0000000002c0ddd8]
Event: 1.515 Thread 0x000000001735a800 nmethod 592% 0x0000000002c0e710 code [0x0000000002c0ec20, 0x0000000002c0fe88]
Event: 1.517 Thread 0x000000001735b800  617   !   3       sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader::checkResource (55 bytes)
Event: 1.518 Thread 0x000000001735b800 nmethod 617 0x0000000002c0c210 code [0x0000000002c0c3c0, 0x0000000002c0ca28]
Event: 1.518 Thread 0x000000001735b800  618       3       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException::<init> (7 bytes)
Event: 1.518 Thread 0x000000001735b800 nmethod 618 0x0000000002c0bd50 code [0x0000000002c0bec0, 0x0000000002c0c108]
Event: 1.519 Thread 0x00000000187e6000  619       4       java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::casTabAt (20 bytes)
Event: 1.520 Thread 0x00000000187e6000 nmethod 619 0x0000000002c0a650 code [0x0000000002c0a780, 0x0000000002c0a7f8]
Event: 1.522 Thread 0x000000001735b800  620       3       java.lang.StringBuffer::<init> (6 bytes)
Event: 1.523 Thread 0x000000001735b800 nmethod 620 0x0000000002c0b810 code [0x0000000002c0b980, 0x0000000002c0bc30]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (1 events):
Event: 1.459 Thread 0x0000000018b72000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002bbefb8 method=javazoom.jl.decoder.huffcodetab.huffman_decoder(Ljavazoom/jl/decoder/huffcodetab;[I[I[I[ILjavazoom/jl/decoder/BitReserve;)I @ 230

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.196 Thread 0x0000000001bef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007975bcc80) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1435]
Event: 0.196 Thread 0x0000000001bef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007975bce90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1435]
Event: 0.503 Thread 0x0000000001bef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007976c6870) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1435]
Event: 0.503 Thread 0x0000000001bef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007976c8548) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1435]
Event: 0.503 Thread 0x0000000001bef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007976c96b8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1435]
Event: 0.503 Thread 0x0000000001bef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007976ce820) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1435]
Event: 0.503 Thread 0x0000000001bef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007976cf478) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1435]
Event: 0.503 Thread 0x0000000001bef000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000007976d00a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1435]
Event: 1.377 Thread 0x0000000018b72000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x0000000797e70768) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1167]
Event: 1.379 Thread 0x0000000018b72000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x0000000797e7e100) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u181\11358\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1167]

Events (10 events):
Event: 1.522 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/FixtureDef
Event: 1.522 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/FixtureDef done
Event: 1.522 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Filter
Event: 1.522 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Filter done
Event: 1.523 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Fixture
Event: 1.523 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Fixture done
Event: 1.523 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/CircleShape
Event: 1.523 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/CircleShape done
Event: 1.523 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ChainShape
Event: 1.523 loading class com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ChainShape done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013fe80000 - 0x000000013feb7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe
0x0000000077bd0000 - 0x0000000077d6f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00000000779b0000 - 0x0000000077acf000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd920000 - 0x000007fefd98a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007feff0b0000 - 0x000007feff18b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefee10000 - 0x000007fefeeaf000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefdd90000 - 0x000007fefddaf000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefecd0000 - 0x000007fefedfd000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077ad0000 - 0x0000000077bca000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefdb90000 - 0x000007fefdbf7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007feff850000 - 0x000007feff85e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feff580000 - 0x000007feff64b000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefc120000 - 0x000007fefc314000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.23403_none_e36ad4593102f066\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007feff900000 - 0x000007feff971000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefdc00000 - 0x000007fefdc2e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefdc30000 - 0x000007fefdd39000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000007feed250000 - 0x000007feed2ff000     C:\Program Files\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Threat Prevention\Ips\EpMPApi.dll
0x000007fefd9c0000 - 0x000007fefd9fb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x000007fefd790000 - 0x000007fefd8fd000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefd770000 - 0x000007fefd77f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x00000000715f0000 - 0x00000000715fc000     C:\Program Files\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Threat Prevention\Ips\EpMPThe.dll
0x0000000078af0000 - 0x0000000078bc2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000603d0000 - 0x0000000060c72000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fee3830000 - 0x000007fee3839000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefdd40000 - 0x000007fefdd8d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefee00000 - 0x000007fefee08000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefb650000 - 0x000007fefb68b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefc810000 - 0x000007fefc81c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000077d80000 - 0x0000000077d87000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000061970000 - 0x000000006197f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000061940000 - 0x0000000061969000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java.dll
0x0000000061920000 - 0x0000000061936000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefdf40000 - 0x000007fefeccb000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefeeb0000 - 0x000007feff0ad000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefd780000 - 0x000007fefd78f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000065ac0000 - 0x0000000065b26000     C:\Users\Kadri01\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxkadri01\69ce8ed5\gdx64.dll
0x000007fefcf60000 - 0x000007fefcf78000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefcc60000 - 0x000007fefcca7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefd9a0000 - 0x000007fefd9bf000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd610000 - 0x000007fefd61f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x0000000061790000 - 0x00000000617aa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefcf00000 - 0x000007fefcf55000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefcef0000 - 0x000007fefcef7000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007feface0000 - 0x000007fefad07000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefacd0000 - 0x000007fefacdb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefab30000 - 0x000007fefab41000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000007fefab50000 - 0x000007fefab68000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x0000000061770000 - 0x0000000061781000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180053000     C:\Users\Kadri01\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxkadri01\dc0f0009\lwjgl64.dll
0x000007fee4d10000 - 0x000007fee4e2d000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x000007fefb740000 - 0x000007fefb76d000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x000007fee4c10000 - 0x000007fee4d01000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x000007fefb790000 - 0x000007fefb798000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x000007feff670000 - 0x000007feff847000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x000007fefdae0000 - 0x000007fefdb16000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x000007feffde0000 - 0x000007feffeba000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefd900000 - 0x000007fefd91a000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000007fefc620000 - 0x000007fefc638000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x00000000023d0000 - 0x0000000002434000     C:\Users\Kadri01\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxkadri01\dc0f0009\OpenAL64.dll
0x000007fefc0c0000 - 0x000007fefc116000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007feff860000 - 0x000007feff8f9000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x000007fefbb90000 - 0x000007fefbcbc000     C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
0x000007fee3b00000 - 0x000007fee3b88000     C:\Windows\system32\dsound.dll
0x000007fefba70000 - 0x000007fefba9c000     C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll
0x000007fefbcc0000 - 0x000007fefbd0b000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x000007fefafb0000 - 0x000007fefafff000     C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x000007feda330000 - 0x000007fedb08b000     C:\Windows\system32\ig9icd64.dll
0x000007fefc9b0000 - 0x000007fefc9c1000     C:\Windows\system32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x000007fedbd50000 - 0x000007fedbdec000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x000007fedbd00000 - 0x000007fedbd42000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x000007fed91d0000 - 0x000007feda32f000     C:\Windows\system32\igc64.dll
0x000007fefd310000 - 0x000007fefd34d000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSTA.dll
0x000000006e9c0000 - 0x000000006ea4c000     C:\Users\Kadri01\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxkadri01\6527a23c\gdx-box2d64.dll
0x000007fef2520000 - 0x000007fef2645000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: com.mygdx.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\EDF04DRV.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\bin;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-backend-headless.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-backend-lwjgl3.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-backend-robovm.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-backend-android.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-backend-gwt.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-natives.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-setup.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-box2d.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-box2d-gwt.jar;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\Projekt\libs\gdx-box2d-natives.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Users\Kadri01\Desktop\eclipse;
USERNAME=kadri01
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.24214)

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 78 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 8027480k(4890620k free), swap 16053060k(12540356k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_181-b13), built on Jul  7 2018 04:01:33 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Mon Aug 27 13:43:23 2018
elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)
```

Comment: Just a guess... Are you running that app in cygwin on the crashing computer and "native" on the non-crashing?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. Until a Minute ago I didn't even know what Cygwin was.